# rust: static map initialization with enum keys

Tags: rust, enums, static, global

First up: I am a very newbie with Rust; learning.

This issue arises most probably from thinking in terms of other languages. So most probably the best solution is doing this in a completely different way. Things don't even compile yet, so apologies if the code has fundamental problems.

I am defining my first trait. The trait function takes 2 parameters, which will define the output.

```
trait SkFormatter {
  fn to_sk(&self, key:Key, is_foreign: bool) -> String;
}
```

The idea is that the implementation would take a string variable, then prepend a string depending on the key, and append a string if `is_foreign` (this latter part is not relevant to the question).

E.g.

> MT-1c2af34
> WD-54bdf36-FX
> WD-ad3425b

As those strings are constant, I was thinking I could do this as a global mapping. So I first created

```
pub enum Key {
  // there are 7 items, but keeping it short here
  Metal,
  Wood,
}
```

Then I wanted to create the mapping, and things started to get tricky.
Tried the HashMap first:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
static KEY_TO_PRE:HashMap<Key,&str> = HashMap::from([
  (Key::Metal,"MT-"),
  (Key::Wood, "WD-"),
]);
```

But this was complaining with

> the trait bound `Key: std::hash::Hash` is not satisfied

Which is surprising to me, as it seems to suggest that the key is not hashable, but I am not defining a type for it, and I would assume that a "unit-like" enum type, as documented, is some kind of integer or something?

I have seen the `match` idiom, maybe I should try that just inside the implementation (global resp. static stuff is smelly to me), but it's not clear to me if the match thing optimizes for reusing, as it will be called over and over.

Just learning...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But this was complaining with
>
> > the trait bound `Key: std::hash::Hash` is not satisfied
>
> Which is surprising to me, as it seems to suggest that the key is not hashable, but I am not defining a type for it, and I would assume that a "unit-like" enum type, as documented, is some kind of integer or something?

The answer to this is to derive the necessary traits on your key type:

```rust
#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Eq, Hash)]
pub enum Key {
  // there are 7 items, but keeping it short here
  Metal,
  Wood,
}
```

> I have seen the `match` idiom, maybe I should try that just inside the implementation (global resp. static stuff is smelly to me), but it's not clear to me if the match thing optimizes for reusing, as it will be called over and over.

I'm not sure what you mean by "optimizes for reusing". But generally we would use `match` if all the strings are known at compile time:

```rust
impl Key {
    fn to_prefix(self) -> &'static str {
        match self {
            Self::Metal => "MT-",
            Self::Wood => "WD-",
            // etc
        }
    }
}
```

Then use that in your `to_sk` function.

Comment: I guess that's exactly what I mean. Yes, they are known at compile time, so this means the compiler will optimize the usage of all the keys, even if called millions of times, correct?

Comment: I still don't know what you mean by "usage of keys". Can you give an example?

Comment: `match` should be faster than a hashmap regardless.

Comment: Usage of keys: every time the fn is called, we need to get "MT-", "WD-" etc. So the idea is that those are statically somewhere just once, and do not need to be allocated on each call. Maybe this is some remnant thinking from other langs though.

Comment: In another example those strings could be much longer, so for the sake of learning, I am wanting to understand what's the best way to allocate such stuff just once.

Comment: @transient_loop One thing to alleviate your concerns: string literals like `"MT-"` do not allocate - the data resides in static memory and you just get a reference to it. And a `match` like this is a simple single conditional. Lookups in a HashMap will have to use more logic to find the element than that.

Comment: @kmdrekoa match like this might compile to a lookup table rather than a conditional. Either way, your point stands.